# How to make sure a cookie will expire?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I feel like my question is fairly simple. I'm using js, and I have a cookie set to expire in 7 days. How can I test that the cookie will expire in 7 days? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` method for this.

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us some code so we can expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the expiration date of a cookie through JavaScript as only key-value pairs are available through document.cookie.

All you can do is check if the cookie exists using the following function:

```
function getCookie(name) { //returns the cookie value or null
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```